# Visual Studio Crashing because of Android layouts

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, android-layout, xamarin.android

i have a little problem with an little android project here.

every time i load a certain project, VS will crash after some seconds. well... i've added each class into a new project and opend it to see when VS crashes, but i figured out, that not the classes were the problem, the layouts made VS crash. the two following(almost exactly the same) codes made it crash seperatly. could you please tell me what is wrong with them?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
  <TableLayout
      android:minWidth="25px"
      android:minHeight="25px"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
      <TextView
          android:text="@string/lbEqID"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:id="@+id/lbEqID" />
      <TextView
          android:text="Small Text"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:layout_column="2"
          android:id="@+id/lbEqIDVar" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
      <TextView
          android:text="@string/lbEqDesc"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:id="@+id/lbEqDesc" />
      <TextView
          android:text="Small Text"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:layout_column="2"
          android:id="@+id/lbEqDescVar" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3">
      <TextView
          android:text="@string/lbTaskID"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:id="@+id/lbTaskID" />
      <TextView
          android:text="Small Text"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:layout_column="2"
          android:id="@+id/lbTaskIDVar" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4">
      <TextView
          android:text="@string/lbTaskDesc"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:id="@+id/lbTaskDesc" />
      <TextView
          android:text="Small Text"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:layout_column="2"
          android:id="@+id/lbTaskDescVar" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5">
      <TextView
          android:text="@string/lbTaskDate"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:id="@+id/lbTaskDate" />
      <TextView
          android:text="Small Text"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:layout_column="2"
          android:id="@+id/lbTaskDateVar" />
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_column="0" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3" />
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4">
            <TextView
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:id="@+id/textView12" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5" />
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6">
            <TextView
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:id="@+id/textView26" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:id="@+id/textView28"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7" />
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow8">
            <TextView
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:id="@+id/textView27" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:id="@+id/textView29"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Learn how to use Visual Studio to debug Visual Studio, and you should get more information about the crash.

Comment: debug itself? could you post me an tutorial or sth? i can't find anything useful about that...

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2009/06/08/9711306.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately VS really cannot tell the problem, so to find a solution here you could create an empty layout and start adding elements one by one. In you case, the problem is that in each TableRow you add two TextViews with columns 0 and 2. If you change column of second one to  "1", Visual Studio will not crash, and I understand this will be the layout you expect.

Comment: i have no more problems right now with this. I abandoned the whole layout (even of other activities) and worked out new ones. but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some issues, but not found a reproducible sample.

Given this looks like a bug, rather than a programming question:

Log this as a repeatable bug with Xamarin using http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ and support@xamarin.com - they should flag this for fixing in an upcoming release, and may be able to assist with a workaround in the meantime.

Comment: It is still early to say whether the crash was caused by a Mono bug. More information (like stack trace) must be collected. As it is very common to see two Visual Studio extension conflict with each other, I guess @user1713668 hit something like that. Simply debug Visual Studio with itself should reveal more information on the crash.

Comment: i've found a very similar bug to the one i have...I'll add a comment to it and try to get the wanted result somehow else. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7403